# Optimize Excel Formula that uses large arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have used the below mentioned excel formula.

```
=INDEX(TABL,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(H2,$A$1:$A$325779)*COUNTIF(I2,"<="&$B$1:$B$325779),ROW(TABL)-MIN(ROW(TABL))+1),1),3)
```

Where "TABL",a table, is A1:E325779 and is the source of my lookup array.

The formula mentioned is the exact requirement but is taking a lot of time to update the excel for 400,000+ cells containing this formula.

Can this be optimized?
Or can this be equated to a faster macro?

Its taking 1 second to update 1 cell!!! That's a very long time to update all 400K+ cells once!!!

Screenshot of a sample worksheet is as below.

[image]

I have based my program on Martin Carlsson's.
it is processing 100 records in 30 seconds. can it be improved?

```
Sub subFindValue()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Cells(2, 12) = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

    Dim varRow As Variant
    Dim varRowMain As Variant
    Dim lookupTable As Variant
    Dim lookupValueTable As Variant

    lookupValueTable = Range("G2:J309011").Value
    lookupTable = Range("A2:D325779").Value

    varRowMain = 1
    varRow = 1

    Do Until varRowMain = 309011
        Do Until varRow = 325779
            If lookupTable(varRow, 1) = lookupValueTable(varRowMain, 1) And lookupTable(varRow, 2) >= lookupValueTable(varRowMain, 2) Then
                lookupValueTable(varRowMain, 3) = lookupTable(varRow, 3)
                lookupValueTable(varRowMain, 4) = lookupTable(varRow, 4)
                Exit Do
            End If
            varRow = varRow + 1
        Loop

        If IsEmpty(lookupValueTable(varRowMain, 3)) Then
            lookupValueTable(varRowMain, 3) = "NA_OX"
            lookupValueTable(varRowMain, 4) = "NA_OY"
        End If

        varRowMain = varRowMain + 1
        varRow = 1
    Loop
    Range("G2:J309011").Value = lookupValueTable

    Cells(3, 12) = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Evaluate the formula then stick in the result in the cell? Have you thought about that?

Comment: Copy Pasting as value comes after the formulas are evaluated. the problem is the formula computation for each cell will take more than 48 hours in any scenario (each cell takes at least 1 sec to update). So looking out for ideas to get faster data processing. Like in the image pasted above, there is just one test data (Gold,2.5), in actual there are 400,000+ such records to be searched out from  300,000+ records of the lookup table.

Comment: consider VBA solution instead of array function, or any built in function. They run different in different threads and I assure you the VBA is much quicker

Comment: Im not too great with formulas but i guess nesting it even further might speed it up a bit. If you are considering a VBA solution then let us know

Comment: I have vrye little VBA experience. will start R&D on the logic mapping then. :) .. If u have some thing in mind to help out with the VBA part please do share it. I do not think there is another alternative. I had created macros to work on duplicate records in another scenario. Completely trust VBA when it comes to speed.!!

Comment: According to this, you can use IF() to short-circuit certain paths. In this case, you could split the two calls to COUNTIF() so that the second COUNTIF() executes only when the first succeeded. This will save you a lot of calculation, especially on 400k+ rows. http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

Comment: I would suggest using Advanced filter if you have 400K rows, since you  have little VBA experience you can also record macro and proceed with it.....Do Google Advanced filter if required....

Comment: I am confused in the screen shot it says that you sort A then B but from your screen shot it looks like A and C are sorted, As row 4 in column B also contains a 3. But if B was sorted, both 3's should be before the 5

Comment: :) when I was preparing the sheet the system was already heavily taxed by the formula running on another sheet. B4 is actually 7.

Comment: Is it possible for you to Sort the Data Descending instead?

Comment: descending, yes. but why?

Comment: Otherwise my answer couldn't work.

Comment: related  - [Replace worksheet array formula with VBA memory array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159105/replace-worksheet-array-formula-with-vba-memory-array/34159106)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work and be much faster then any VBA solution that would require looping every row as long as you can sort the date in Column B Descending:

Enter the following Formula As an Array (Instead of Enter use Ctrl+Shift+Enter

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$15,MATCH(G2,IF($A$1:$A$15=F2,$B$1:$B$15),-1))
```

You should end up with something like:

[image]

Explanation:

```
IF($A$1:$A$15=F2,$B$1:$B$15)
```

Is building an array of values equal to the rows in column B where The Test word is in the same Row column A.

```
MATCH(G2,IF($A$1:$A$15=F2,$B$1:$B$15),-1)
```

This is using the Array built from the Id statement to find the smallest value greater than or equal to the Look up value from test data.

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$15,MATCH(G2,IF($A$1:$A$15=F2,$B$1:$B$15),-1))
```

Once it is all together the 'INDEX' will return the value in Column C that is at the same position as the matched value.

***UPDATE:*** If you are looking for what tigeravatar's Answer returns then here is another VBA function that will return all values:

```
Sub GetValues()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Dim strMetalName As String: strMetalName = [E3]
Dim dbMinimumValue As Double: dbMinimumValue = [F3]

Range("G3:G" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

With Range("TABL")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strMetalName
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & dbMinimumValue, Operator:=xlAnd
     Range("C2", [C2].End(xlDown)).Copy [G3]
    .AutoFilter
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```

For me his took 5-7 minutes to run while this took 1.5  seconds, where my first answer returns the single row containing the closest matching result this sub will return ALL values greater then or equal too.

Comment: Thanks .. in this scenario I agree.. given that I used =INDEX(TABL,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(H2,$A$1:$A$325779)*COUNTIF(I2,"<="&$B$1:$B$325779),ROW(TABL)-MIN(ROW(TABL))+1),1),3) it just increased the number of calculations. Index Match works faster. 1, 0, -1 as the last parameter gives the intended output. The last parameter -1 does it all. Only as you said, it should be in descending sort :). <-1> The MATCH function will find the smallest value that is greater than or equal to value. You should be sure to sort your array in descending order.

Comment: It took under 4 hours but did it. It started off with a quick increment in the process completed percentage status. slowed down later. but worked faster than anything i used!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
Sub subFindValue()
    'Speed up
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim strNamedValue As String: strNamedValue = Range("E3")
    Dim curHigherThanValue As Currency: curHigherThanValue = Range("F3")
    Dim varRow As Variant

    varRow = 1
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(varRow, 1))
        If Cells(varRow, 1) = strNamedValue And Cells(varRow, 2) > curHigherThanValue Then
            Range("G3") = Cells(varRow, 3)
            Exit Do
        End If
        varRow = varRow + 1
        Loop

    'Slow down
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I have modified the code to run on an outer loop with a range of test values. Seems it will do the trick. Though slow but faster then the formula. Will update in a while.

Comment: For speed use: Pivot tables or filter. For extreme speed use: [Power Pivot](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx)

Comment: I have updated my code that is based on your sample code in the main message. Can it be made faster?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is sorted on column 2 within column 1 then the SpeedTools Filter.Ifs function would be considerable faster than your formula (at least 50 times faster)

```
=FILTER.IFS(2,$A$1:$C$325779,3,1,E3,2,">" & F3)
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of SpeedTools which is a commercial Excel addin product. 
You can download a full trial version from:
 http://www.decisionmodels.com/FastExcelV3SpeedTools.htm

Comment: Will explore this option for sure.. something new.

Comment: On the test data I gave, it returns the right o/p. On my actual sheet it returns 0 as the value. i checked the formula syntax. FILTER.IFS(nsortedCols,InputRange,ReturnCol,CriteriaColumn1,Criteria1,CriteriaColumn2,Criteria2) .. my inputs are correct ... suggestions?

Comment: Can you send me a sample of your actual data and the Filter.IFS formula that returns 0?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to adjust where the output goes (it assumes that the results should be output in cell G3 and down), but this should run pretty quickly:

```
Sub subFindValue()

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim varFind As Variant
    Dim dCompare As Double
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim strFirst As String

    varFind = Range("E3").Text
    dCompare = Range("F3").Value2

    Range("G3:G" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

    With Range("TABL").Resize(, 1)
        Set rngFound = .Find(varFind, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            ReDim arrResults(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, varFind), 1 To 1)
            strFirst = rngFound.Address
            Do
                If rngFound.Offset(, 1).Value > dCompare Then
                    ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
                    arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = rngFound.Offset(, 2).Text
                End If
                Set rngFound = .Find(varFind, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
        End If
    End With

    If ResultIndex > 0 Then Range("G3").Resize(ResultIndex).Value = arrResults

End Sub
```

Comment: speeds the same if not slower than the current one.

Comment: Really? On a dataset of over 500,000 rows with over 23,000 results the code completes for me in about 2 seconds.  Martin Carlsson's code on the same dataset takes several minutes to complete...

Comment: minutes! .. well i have an intel i3 and 8 gb ram with MS office 2010 32 bit on Windows 8 x64. Perhaps that is the cause. I have left it running for hours and it hangs in the end.

Comment: @Vishal I have created an example file that can be downloaded [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz-nM5djZBWYU1JsbS0xeHk4dHM/edit?usp=sharing).  The sample file has 500,000 rows and with a minimum value of 2.5 returns over 20,000 results.  On my machine, the macro completes in just over 3 seconds.  Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: @tigeravatar I have no idea what kind of computer your running to have that code execute in 3 seconds with your sample file, I downloaded your file and ran it and it took 320 seconds (5.3 minutes) to execute. Out of curiosity was there a reason you choose `.Find(varFind, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)` over `.FindNext(After:=rngFound)`? Also seeing as his data is sorted I added a VBA sub that will return all results >= to criteria, my original answer was based on his picture that returned only single result.

Comment: I stopped using `.FindNext` when I found that it was consistently slower.  See [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/839149-speed-of-range-find-vs-range-findnext.html) for details

Comment: @tigeravatar, the columns E & F in your file has one input. In my file there are 300,000+ inputs. so 300,000 inputs searched in 500,000 records in column A & B. That's what takes time. The formula I selected as the answer did it in under 4 hours. that too when I used it to check "=" first and if not found to get the record against least higher value. I have detailed the outcome in the reply to the selected answer post. Though I believe VBA is faster and much more agile in general, but this time the formula got me the result.