# Slow sheets and crashes because of formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've got a sheet in Excel which actually is a kind of a database with people in it. Because I need to have their real-time age, I have a formula which calculates this.

```
=IF(I2="";"";IF(MONTH(DATE())>MONTH(I2),YEAR(DATE())-YEAR(I2),
IF(AND(MONTH(DATE())=MONTH(I2),DAY(DATE())>=DAY(I2)),
YEAR(DATE())-YEAR(I2),(YEAR(DATE())-YEAR(I2))-1)))
```

You can probably imagine that this is a relatively slow code. Because everyday multiple people will be added I need to have this code for the complete column. This is so intensive that the excel on my work-pc crashes (not much ram) and everything I do on that sheet gets slow.

What's the best way to solve this? I thought it may help to not calculte `DATE()` everytime so I put this in another cell and referenced to that cell everytime, but it only became worse.

**Edit:**

Format of my sheet:

I2-I10: 08-01-1994 (birth-date) P2-P1048576: formula (will return 22)

Column A has cells with Text/String data values, column B has Default

Even though it's in Dutch, hopefully this will make it a little more clear:

[image: Example]

Comment: A shorter formula,...`=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"y")`

Comment: It looks like you want to get the years between column I and today(). What column Gets the results?

Comment: I tried it but it's still slow, less than before though

Comment: Column P gets the results

Comment: If this is anywhere north of 10K rows, use bulk loading of values to variant array(s) then in-memory processing and returning to the worksheet *en masse*. Typically takes 1-4% of the time for native worksheet formula calculation. See [Replace worksheet array formula with VBA memory array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159105/replace-worksheet-array-formula-with-vba-memory-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- `=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"Y")` this will return number of years from the given date in cell `A1`.  .
- `=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"M")` this will return number of months from the given date in cell `A1`.  .
- `=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"D")` this will return number of days from the given date in cell `A1`.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some VBA will work in this situation. Test this out, Delete the formulas in Column P and then run this code, It loops through column I and places the difference in column P

```
Sub DteDif()
    Dim Rws As Long, rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim d As Date

    d = Now
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("I2:I" & Rws)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        c.Offset(, 7) = Int(DateDiff("d", c, d) / 365.25)
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like using VBA is indeed the best and fastest solution. I need to check the ages very regularly, and I need a precise answer. Therefore I made it like in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the following is the most easy, fast and precise solution. If you think otherwise, I'll be glad to hear it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

i = 2

While Sheets("shtData").Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    If Month(Date) > Month(CDate(Sheets("shtData").Cells(i, kolGD))) Then
        Sheets("shtData").Cells(i, kolLT) = Year(Date) - Year(CDate(Sheets("shtData").Cells(i, kolGD)))
    Else
        If Month(Date) = Month(CDate(Sheets("shtData").Cells(i, kolGD))) And Day(Date) >= Day(CDate(Sheets("shtData").Cells(i, kolGD))) Then
            Sheets("shtData").Cells(i, kolLT) = Year(Date) - Year(CDate(Sheets("shtData").Cells(i, kolGD)))
        Else
            Sheets("shtData").Cells(i, kolLT) = Year(Date) - Year(CDate(Sheets("shtData").Cells(i, kolGD))) - 1
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```