# Find value in column, based on 2 criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file with 3 columns. Column A contains 300,000 rows, with about 200 separate IDs, all duplicated at least 1,000 times. Column B contains the date for each of the rows. Column C contains the values that I need to extract.

Each of the 200 IDs in Col A can have multiple values (e.g. ID 1234 might have dates 1/1/2001, 1/3/2001, 1/2/2015, etc). Similarly, each date on Col B will have multiple IDs (e.g. 1/2/15 might have IDs of 1234, 1874, 1930, 6043, etc).

In a nutshell, I need to check the values in Col A and Col B to find the relevant ID in Col A and the maximum value in Col B, and return the value in the relevant cell in Col C.

I've looked at Index/Match examples, but they don't seem to be suitable. Is there any suggestions on a macro I could run, that would accomplish what is needed.

Comment: People requesting help with VBA code are **expected** to show original effort. Get started on something and come back to show your own attempt(s).

Comment: Hint: Have a look at the array formulas below and then see the code in [Replace worksheet array formula with VBA memory array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159105/replace-worksheet-array-formula-with-vba-memory-array).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very informative

Comment: btw, these array formulas only take several seconds to process 200 individual IDs against a AGGREGATE for conditional max to return an associated value from 300K rows. Given that the data must be fairly static, is VBA really necessary?

Comment: In this case, it is necessary, as the data that is inputted into the rows will change, depending on the values being extracted from the system. The largest extract is about 900k, the smallest about 30 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$300000,MATCH(1,IF(($A$1:$A$300000="1234")*($B$1:$B$300000=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$300000="1234",$B$1:$B$300000))),1,0),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Change the `"1234"` to a reference cell with the appropriate ID.

Comment: Damn, beat me by 4 seconds :-P

Comment: @Scott Craner - Thank you for the formula. How would I implement this formula into a VBA command, instead of having the formula implemented in an Excel cell?

Comment: @Clauric SO is not a code for me site.  If you have code that is not working then put that in your original post and ask a specific question about what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Think I got it sorted with the MAX formula

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using array formulas. To start, you can retrieve the maximum date in column B when column A is 1234 using the below formula. Keep in mind that you have to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when you finish typing an array formula.

```
{=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$24=1234,$B$2:$B$24))}
```

Note that you will need to change the ranges to include all of your data, rather than my test data on rows 2-24.

Now that you have a formula to retrieve the max date, you can put that inside an index/match and, again using Ctrl-Shift-Enter, use the below array formula to retrieve the value in column C for a row matching 1234 and the maximum date.

```
{=INDEX($C$2:$C$24,MATCH(1234&MAX(IF($A$2:$A$24=1234,$B$2:$B$24)),$A$2:$A$24&$B$2:$B$24,0))}
```

Comment: Must be the right method if we both did similar. :)

Comment: @Nick Peranzi - Thank you for the formulae. How would I implement these formulae into a VBA command, instead of having the formulae implemented in an Excel cells?

Comment: @Clauric can you be a bit more specific? This can be implemented in VBA in many ways, from a UDF that would return the relevant value from column C for one specific value in column A, to entering the array formula in a large range of cells, to entering the output values (static, non-formulas) in a list of unique IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Think I got it sorted with the MAX formula