# Excel read entire column- extract results in other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need an excel formula that help me to do the following. I want to read a "letter" in one column (B), and "extract" the values in the column next to it (A). Example Below: In the "Result" column of the example below my formula reads all the "g"s of column B and then write all the corresponding values. I have not been able to use VLOOKUP because always gives me the first value of the first "g" that finds. Is there a way to use VLOOKUP here. My current solution is the following formula

```
{=INDEX($A:$B,SMALL(IF($B:$B=J$5,ROW($B:$B)),ROW(1:1)),1)}
```

(J$5, is just the cell in which I have the letter "g", item to look for in column B). Although this formula worked, there are two drawbacks: 1) Once it finds no more "g" the return is "#NUM!", which I do not like, I which I get just a empty cell if it does not find more and 2) this formula is kind of slow, not a big deal, but I never so this before on my computer. Your input is highly appreciated.

---

```
    Column A    Column B  Result (letter g(J$5))
    23             f        27
    27             g        87
    34             h        54
    56             h        88
    87             g        4
    35             f        
    8              f        
    54             g        
    468            h        
    88             g        
    90             f        
    4              g
```

Comment: Would [Replace worksheet array formula with VBA memory array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159105) help?

Comment: Jeeped, not really sure how to do that. Could you please elaborate more. The post you suggested is not clear for me. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 3):

Array formulas will always be slow on large data sets. Consider using Advanced filter instead of an array formula. The setup looks like this:

[image]

You can find an introduction to advanced filter here: [Excel Advanced Filter Introduction](http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html)

Comment: Thanks Teylyn. This works great except that I would like the "result" column, in your example the "number - advance filter" column to be automaticlly updated as the data in the "list rage" changes. That is, adding, removing or changing values. Is it possible to auto-refresh the "advance filter" option?

Comment: I figure I could use your suggestion with a Macro record in which I refresh with a ctrl+something. That is sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

An array formula version FYI (you might want to name the range $C$3:$C$18 for simplicity):

(Click the formula for the image)

[=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL(IF($C$3:$C$18=$F$2,ROW($C$3:$C$18),""),ROW()-ROW($F$2)),COLUMN($B$2))),"")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuZOG.png)