# VBA Alternative for sumproduct function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, sum

I tried to use SUMIFS, but it failed since the formula doesn't allow me to use two different criterias from the same criteria range (which makes sense of course), so I looked around the Internet and found '=SUMPRODUCT' instead I used it but it doesn't return any value. Here my formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!E:E="DB")+('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!E:E="DZ"))*('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!G:G))
```

Maybe Looping through the range with an if clause and using the sum function after "then"?

In row number 26 & 27 are two different string values ("DB,DZ") and in the same row is a value in the column (Betrag) which means amount and I need a formula to sum all values that are in the same rows as "DB" and "DZ"
[image]

Comment: I find it unlikely that you have data down to the 1,048,576th row in column E or column G. Cut your full column references down to the actual extents of your data. Also, see [Replace worksheet array formula with VBA memory array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159105/replace-worksheet-array-formula-with-vba-memory-array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jeeped that you should "*Cut your full column references down to the actual extents of your data*"

There is a **slight typo** in your formula. Replace the `*` with a `,` and it will work just fine :)

Your original formula should be

`=SUMPRODUCT((('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!E1:E6="DB")+('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!E1:E6="DZ")), 'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!G1:G6)`

Replace 6 with the relevant row.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can improve your existing formula without more information.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!E1:INDEX('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!E:E, MATCH("zzz", 'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!E:E))={"DB","DZ"})*('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!G1:INDEX('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!G:G, MATCH("zzz", 'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!E:E))))
```

It may look more complicated but it actually performs much less work.

Actually, this may be even better.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!G:G, 'BB_Juni 2016_Crew'!E:E, {"DB","DZ"}))
```

Both are standard formulas (no need for CSE).

Comment: I added a picture maybe this helps to clarify what I am looking for!

Comment: I don't retype sample data from images. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a spreadsheet function `AND` that accepts several conditions and returns TRUE of all conditions are TRUE, FALSE otherwise.

You may try re-phrasing your formula or make your question clearer so it may be possible to give you an actual working formula.